# Applying padding or margin to the container of floating content

Tags: html, css

Consider the following html structure:

```
<div class="entry">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <div class="tagged">...</div>
    <div class="comments">...</div>
</div>
```

The css is:

```
.taggged { float: left; width: 50%; }
.comments { float: right; width: 50%; text-align: right; }
.entry { margin-bottom: 30px; }
```

The issue is that the margin (or padding, if applicable) does not render at the bottom of the `.entry` element. What I've tried `overflow:  auto` on the `.entry` and various permutations of `clear:`

Comment: I've found several near dups on SO and applied their answers with no luck. Please do not close this for duplicate.

Comment: Have you tried either adding a float left to the entry div or clearing the floats ?

Comment: I think a http://jsfiddle.net or a http://jsbin.com is needed here..

Comment: What comes after the entry div? Another one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd try

`.entry { overflow:hidden; margin-bottom:30px; }`

Another thing that works better in my experience, is to have the right floated element first in the source order, like this:

```
<div class="entry">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <div class="comments">...</div>
    <div class="tagged">...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: +1 for right first. I know that's helped in the past. I don't have time to test any of these right now but I'll get to it later this evening.

Answer (score 1):

Add an element (div or span) after your comments and give it clear:both; in your styles.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what else may be in your code, but just adding the `overflow: auto` (or `hidden`) is working for me in FF, Chrome, and IE7+ on [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/86fs4/1/). I know you said you tried the first.

Answer (score 1):

It seemed that it was able to tweak it to work in the following way:

CSS:

```
 body { overflow: hidden; }
.taggged { float: left; width: 50%; }
.comments { float: right; width: 50%; text-align: right; margin-bottom: 30px; }
.entry { overflow: auto; width: 100%; }
```

Moved the margin to be on the bottom div, and changed entry to `width: 100%; overflow: auto;`. I tested it and it works on Firefox and Opera.

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html